# Can I say "I am twenty years young."

Tags: word-usage

I found someone wrote this on the thread.

"I am 65 years young."

We are so used to say "young" at the end but I was convinced by intention.

Without the sense of metaphor or poetic approach, is it appropriate to say in our daily conversation?

Comment: I would have thought twenty was far too young for such irony to mean anything much. In fact, such an expression might have the unintended effect of identifying you as old for your years. I would wait until you are at least fifty before using it, if I were you.

Comment: Yes, as a joke.

Answer (score 5):

At least in America, saying "I am X years young" is a very informal, and normally somewhat humorous, way of saying "I am X years old." Its usage nowadays is typically restricted to address the age of someone, usually in their 40s or older, while attempting to "dance around" (in a joking manner) the fact that they are as old as they are. I think it is a good example of the prevalence of "youth culture" in America.

Strictly speaking, it is incorrect to say ". . .years young." Always use ". . .years old," *especially* when the situation is even the slightest bit formal.

As a real-world example, when I was a kid in elementary school, it was common for the administrators to announce a teacher's birthday over intercom. They would *always* say "Mr/s. [teacher] turned X years young today!" The reason it is supposed to be slightly jocular is because people often don't want to get any older than they already are.

Comment: I'm curious to understand why you would consider it "American". The celebration of youth features generally in western society. This is in contrast to Asia, where in some communities age is not only revered but celebrated. "Ninety-years young", is an idiomatic and playful ironic figure. It can, though, be overdone.

Comment: I said "in America" because I am an American. I initially typed "in the West," but I have no real personal experience or knowledge of what "age culture" is like anywhere but where I live - and so I restricted my statement to where I am certain it applies.

Answer (score 3):

How old — I mean young — are those who are said to be "X years young"?

I searched The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=101812418) for `* years young`, then went through the entire list to convert words to numbers, fix errors, and remove false positives. I also removed two outliers, 200 and 14 *billion*. (Note: not all of these hits refer to people!) Then, I graphed it as a [histogram](https://www.statskingdom.com/histogram-maker.html):

[image: Bucket size 5]

The mean is 66.6 years: Most often this expression is said humorously of older people, conveying that despite their age they shouldn't be considered "old". It is chill, informal, casual.

However, there are quite a few examples where it's someone really young being talked about. For example, the [Washington Post](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Speech_Representation_in_the_History_of/ES8DEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=at%2014%20years%20young&pg=PA7):

> "And now — at 14 years young — Hunter Lussi!" brayed race director Bob Vigorito, who greeted each finisher over a loudspeaker.

---

Raw numbers (unordered):

```
80, 80, 80, 80, 53, 53, 53, 53, 40, 40, 40, 40, 86, 86, 86, 86, 92, 92, 92, 92, 100, 100, 74, 74, 74, 37, 37, 37, 28, 28, 50, 50, 38, 38, 91, 91, 90, 90, 88, 88, 87, 87, 83, 83, 82, 82, 81, 85, 85, 80, 80, 94, 94, 129, 125, 68, 72, 71, 70, 17, 40, 51, 99, 97, 95, 37, 64, 47, 125, 52, 83, 84, 78, 77, 76, 75, 52, 51, 72, 67, 64, 63, 62, 59, 58, 57, 68, 55, 54, 75, 49, 43, 35, 32, 31, 26, 25, 22, 21, 20, 17, 14, 128, 106, 100, 10, 53
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly grammatical unambiguous to say you're "20 years young", but this phrasing is really designed to subvert the more traditional phrasing "20 years old". If you say it this way, you're really putting emphasis on your youthfulness rather than your age itself.

You'll typically see this form used when describing older people, as you originally saw with "65 years young". The person is highlighting the fact that their numerical age may not align with how old they *feel* or perceive themselves. 20 is already a young age, so saying you're "20 years young" doesn't have the same sort of slightly humorous, sardonic twist to it.

Answer (score -3):

It is not grammatically correct as far as I know, but there's nothing wrong with saying it! I mean, it makes sense! It is very informal, so I don't recommend saying it to the Queen of England, but other than that, say it as much as you like!

Comment: Your answer is not without unintended irony as the Queen of England is currently ninety-five years young! And I'm sure she would receive the remark graciously if you told her so.

Answer (score -5):

Saying 'I am X years young' simply shows a limit. Young from what? This can even assume that one knows when their lifetime will end. On the other hand, saying 'I am X years old' shows from where you have come from. Hence 'old' is the right term since it shows how far and advanced you are other than 'young' which shows how near you are to your limit.